# Linking vapor to own openssl compilation

Tags: swift, macos, openssl, linkage

I don't want to use brew, or anything which requires sudo permission.

As a user with no admin permission I compiled openssl 1.1.0 and install it at `$HOME/openssl`.

Then I downloaded vapor 3.3 https://github.com/vapor/vapor/archive/3.3.0.tar.gz and I want it to be linked with my openssl compilation.

However when building it with `swift build -Xcc -I$HOME/openssl/include -Xlinker -L$HOME/openssl/lib/` I get the following error:

```
warning: you may be able to install openssl using your system-packager:
     brew install libressl

'swift-nio-zlib-support' zlib.pc: warning: couldn't find pc file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ASN1_STRING_get0_data", referenced from:
      _CNIOOpenSSL_ASN1_STRING_get0_data in shims.c.o
     (maybe you meant: _CNIOOpenSSL_ASN1_STRING_get0_data)
  "_ASN1_STRING_length", referenced from:
      _$s10NIOOpenSSL22SubjectAltNameSequenceC4nextAA18OpenSSLCertificateC011AlternativeE0OSgyF in SSLCertificate.swift.o
  "_ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8", referenced from:
      _$s10NIOOpenSSL18OpenSSLCertificateC10commonNameSays5UInt8VGSgyF in SSLCertificate.swift.o
  "_BIO_clear_flags", referenced from:
      _CNIOOpenSSL_BIO_clear_retry_flags in shims.c.o
  "_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
      _CNIOOpenSSL_BIO_get_close in shims.c.o
      _CNIOOpenSSL_BIO_set_close in shims.c.o
      _CNIOOpenSSL_BIO_get_mem_data in shims.c.o
...
```

Using OS X 10.14.4 and Xcode 10.1.